# Write a loop around async await that will read and write a files in parallel?

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, async-await, phantomjs

I'm using `fs` and `phantomJS`

```
const phantom = require('phantom');
const fs = require('fs');
```

I have **4 routes** (urls) that get opened from phantom JS.  When opened, the page content is read and then `node.fs` will write out that content into it's own html files.

```
const routes = [
  'about',
  'home',
  'todo',
  'lazy',
]
```

---

### **Question:**

---

**How do I loop over this async function for every value in `const routes` in parallel.**

```
(async function() {
  const instance = await phantom.create();
  const page = await instance.createPage();
  const status = await page.open(`http://localhost:3000/${routes}`);
  const content = await page.property('content');

  await fsPromise(`${routes}.html`, content);

  await instance.exit();
}());

const fsPromise = (file, str) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.writeFile(file, str, function (err) {
      if (err) return reject(err);
      resolve(`${routes} > ${routes}.html`);
    });
  })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a while to get this actually up and running in an environment that supports `await` and `async`. It turns out Node v7.5.0 supports them - way simpler than fighting with babel! The only other thorn in this investigation was that `request-promise`, which I was using to test, doesn't seem to fail gracefully when the promise isn't built properly. I saw a lot of errors like this when I tried to use `await` with it:

```
return await request.get(options).map(json => json.full_name + ' ' + json.stargazers_count);
                 ^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

In the end though, I realized that your promise function doesn't actually use async/await (which is why mine errored), so the premise should be the same. Here's the test that I got working — it's very similar to yours. The key is in the synchronous `for()` iteration:

```
var request = require('request-promise')
var headers = { 'User-Agent': 'YOUR_GITHUB_USERID' }
var repos = [
    'brandonscript/usergrid-nodejs',
    'facebook/react',
    'moment/moment',
    'nodejs/node',
    'lodash/lodash'
]

function requestPromise(options) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get(options).then(json => resolve(json.full_name + ' ' + json.stargazers_count))
    })
}

(async function() {
    for (let repo of repos) {
        let options = {
            url: 'https://api.github.com/repos/' + repo,
            headers: headers,
            qs: {}, // or you can put client_id / client secret here
            json: true
        };
        let info = await requestPromise(options)
        console.log(info)
    }
})()
```

And while I can't test it, I'm pretty sure this will work:

```
const routes = [
    'about',
    'home',
    'todo',
    'lazy',
]

(async function() {
    for (let route of routes) {
        const instance = await phantom.create();
        const page = await instance.createPage();
        const status = await page.open(`http://localhost:3000/${route}`);
        const content = await page.property('content');

        await fsPromise(`${route}.html`, content);

        await instance.exit();
    }
}())
```

Since you're using ES7 syntax, you should also be able to get the `fsPromise()` function to perform without declaring a promise:

```
async const fsPromise = (file, str) => {
    return await fs.writeFile(file, str)
}
```